# How to use Reflection to set Value Types in a call chain correctly

Tags: c#, reflection, properties, value-type

So I'm writing a parser that uses an xml document to create a group of objects and fill in their properties. I want a user to be able to with attributes put a property like position.x="5" and the X position gets set to 5.

My issue is value type fields can easily be modified with the code below as I can mutate the original value, but value type properties return a copy that will have to get modified and reassigned back to the source object. Any ideas on how to handle value type properties?

Example: position is a struct of type Vector2 that is a property. MyObject.position.x = 5 will not work because calling SetValue on position will 
create a temporary position and set x to 5 on it. Therefore, the actual position attached to the object will not get the value of 5. If I do MyObject.position = new Vector2(5,0) I will get the position set to 5,0 since I am not attempting to mutate the position elements and instead assigning an entire value to position.

Note: I wrote some extension methods so 'GetValue' is valid on member info.

```
private bool SetAttributeValue(string text,object obj,MemberInfo setter)
{
    BuildParseMethods();
    if (!TryParseAttribute(text, setter.GetMemberType(), out object value))
        return false;

    setter.SetValue(obj, value);

    return true;
}


private void SetChainAttribute(XmlAttribute attribute,object instance)
{
    object target = instance;
    MemberInfo[] bindings = null;
    string[] parts = attribute.Name.Split('.');

    Type type = instance.GetType();
    for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
    {
        bindings = type.GetMember(parts[i], BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.SetField | BindingFlags.SetProperty | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase);

        if (bindings == null || bindings.Length == 0)
        {
            Debug.LogError($"Unable to find element {i} of {attribute.Name}");
            return;
        }

        if (i < parts.Length - 1)
        {
            target = bindings[0].GetValue(target);
            type = target != null ? target.GetType() : bindings[0].GetType();
        }
    }

    SetAttributeValue(attribute.Value, target, bindings[0]);
}
```

Comment: I've read this a couple of times, and its a little unclear what the problem is, and how it relates to the code, or what you are trying to do (though it could be just me)

Comment: @MichaelRandall I added some code and tried to clarify it better with an example.

Answer (score 0):

Structs in C# are supposed to be immutable, so that when pass structs as parameters, returned from a property / method, the compiler creates copies of structs to prevent it from being modified.

As you may have realized, you could set `Position` property to override the entire `Vector2`, so you could follow that path in your reflection code:

```
var myObj = new MyObject();
myObj.Position = new Vector2();
// This produces error CS1612 Cannot modify the return value of 'MyObject.Position' because it is not a variable
myObj.Position.X = 5; 

// Workaround:
// Use reflection to set Position instead of Position.X
var prop = myObj.GetType().GetProperty("Position");
prop.SetValue(myObj, Activator.CreateInstance(prop.PropertyType, 5));
```

The `Activator.CreateInstance` finds the correct constructor of `Vector2` to call based on the arguments provided.

Another alternative way is to use boxed struct on your `MyObject`:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing

```
interface IVector2
{
    int X { get; set; }
}

struct Vector2 : IVector2
{
}

class MyObject
{
    public IVector2 BoxedPosition { get; set; }
}
```

Boxed struct can "survive" the copy issue, but there might be performance trade off and you must have access to the source code of `Vector2`.